# shooting a ball at an angle?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, animation, angle

When I shoot the ball out of my cannon, the ball does not shoot exactly at the mouse position of the mouse click. At certain angles it seems fine, but others its off by several degrees. Is this the correct formualas?

thanks

```
public function setPos() {
    destX = gameManager.stage.mouseX;
    destY = gameManager.stage.mouseY;
    var dx:Number = destX -gameManager.tank.x;
    var dy:Number = destY - gameManager.tank.y;

    radians = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
}

public function Shoot() {
     this.x +=  speed *  Math.cos(radians);
    this.y +=  speed *Math.sin(radians);
}
```

Comment: I formatted your code as code (use the {} button or indent 4 spaces to do this yourself the next time around) and added some tags.

Answer (score 1):

That looks right at first glance.

How are you determining that it is "off"?. Have you accounted for the registration point on "tank"? Is it off consistently in the same vectors or is it random? I don't suppose that you have the swf posted on the web somewhere?

Comment: The bullet spawns from the center of the tank and moves to where the mouse is clicked. when I draw a line from the center of the tank to the point of the mouse the bullet does not follow the line. It is off by a "few" degrees but its off by the same amount.

Comment: +1 for "Have you accounted for the registration point". But check for the reg point on the cannon, and the ball.